# Pandas - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pipe'

Tags: python, pandas

I loaded a csv, tried to pipe some functions and get the following error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pipe'

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

def func1(df):
    df['newcol'] = ...some code

def func2(df):
    df['newcol2'] = ...some code

(
df.pipe(func1)
 .pipe(func2)
)
```

when I print out df, it prints the dataframe normally. No idea why I get that error. Pandas v0.24.2. Python v3.7

Comment: I would imagine that df.pipe(func1) does the calculation in place and does not return "self" but instead returns "None".  You would have to run it on two separate lines.  The documentation says otherwise though, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I think I see, you need to return your dataframe out of func1 and func2.  It says in the docs that pipe returns "object : the return type of func.", which is currently None.

Comment: @tmwilson26 Interesting. That worked. I followed the chained pipelining as they show in the Pandas documentation df.pipe(func1).pipe(func2)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to `return df` from func1 as it is input to func2.
I had same issue as I was not returning df from a function in middle. Hope this helps!!